# Django crispy forms shows password as clear text

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

Crispy forms currently shows my password field as clear text. I have tried the following but I still cannot get it to use type=password.

```
Fieldset(
            'Enter a password.',
            PrependedText('password', '<i class="fa fa-key"></i>',
                          placeholder='Password',
                          autocomplete='off',
                          widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                          ),
        ),
```

I have  also tired `type="password"` with no effect.

I get no error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm 99.9% positive that you missed adding the widget to the form field declaration. You should have something like this in order to display a password field:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    ...
```

And the layout should be as simple as:

```
Layout(
    PrependedText('password', '@', placeholder="password", autocomplete='off')
)
```

The `widget=` keyword argument is defined on the Django's `forms.CharField` constructor and not on the django-cryspy-forms' `bootstrap.PrependedText` constructor.

You can find more information on Django forms fields [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/).

### UPDATE

If you have a model form, it's being constructed from your model, either automatically (eg using the admin views), by using `modelform_factory` or by defining the ModelForm yourself. Here is an example of the 3rd approach.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = (... fields you want to include in the form ...)

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, ...)
```

Please note that by providing your model form field override, you'll have to also provide attributes like label, help_text (and such) because they will not be automatically copied from the model field.

Comment: This is a model form tho?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a model form. The model form is a form that is built for a particular model instance (database row). You'll have to instruct your modelform password field to use a PasswordInput widget.

Answer (score 2):

I never had good luck with `crispy-forms` and formsets, so I just use forms directly in templates. See if that works:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form|crispy }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        <input id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id" type="hidden" value="{{ form.instance.pk }}"/>
        {{ form|crispy }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define PasswordInput.

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):

password = forms.CharField(label='Enter Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'alphanumeric password'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: **forms.py** file.

```
    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('email', 'password')

        // add this to make password field 'password' type
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'type': 'password'}),
        }
```